# Apply uploaded image into canvas after resizing/moving it around

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I can upload an image into the canvas and being able to resize and move it around. Now i want to apply the image into the canvas when i'm done moving it, for example, when i press the 'enter' key or something else (can be any other solution), so that i can upload another image and place it alongside the previous one.

This is what i have:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pedrovil/tLf253zd/)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;

var startX;
var startY;
var isDown = false;


var pi2 = Math.PI * 2;
var resizerRadius = 8;
var rr = resizerRadius * resizerRadius;
var draggingResizer = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};
var imageX = 50;
var imageY = 50;
var imageWidth, imageHeight, imageRight, imageBottom;
var draggingImage = false;
var startX;
var startY;

function el(id){return document.getElementById(id);}

var img = new Image();

function readImage() {
    if ( this.files && this.files[0] ) {
        var FR= new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function(e) {
           img = new Image();
           img.onload = function() {
             imageWidth = img.width;
             imageHeight = img.height;
             imageRight = imageX + imageWidth;
             imageBottom = imageY + imageHeight
             draw(true, false);
           };
           img.src = e.target.result;
        };       
        FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
    }
}

el("fileUpload").addEventListener("change", readImage, false);


function draw(withAnchors, withBorders) {

    // clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // draw the image
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, imageX, imageY, imageWidth, imageHeight);

    // optionally draw the draggable anchors
    if (withAnchors) {
        drawDragAnchor(imageX, imageY);
        drawDragAnchor(imageRight, imageY);
        drawDragAnchor(imageRight, imageBottom);
        drawDragAnchor(imageX, imageBottom);
    }

    // optionally draw the connecting anchor lines
    if (withBorders) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(imageX, imageY);
        ctx.lineTo(imageRight, imageY);
        ctx.lineTo(imageRight, imageBottom);
        ctx.lineTo(imageX, imageBottom);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    }

}

function drawDragAnchor(x, y) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, resizerRadius, 0, pi2, false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

function anchorHitTest(x, y) {

    var dx, dy;

    // top-left
    dx = x - imageX;
    dy = y - imageY;
    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
        return (0);
    }
    // top-right
    dx = x - imageRight;
    dy = y - imageY;
    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
        return (1);
    }
    // bottom-right
    dx = x - imageRight;
    dy = y - imageBottom;
    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
        return (2);
    }
    // bottom-left
    dx = x - imageX;
    dy = y - imageBottom;
    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
        return (3);
    }
    return (-1);

}


function hitImage(x, y) {
    return (x > imageX && x < imageX + imageWidth && y > imageY && y < imageY + imageHeight);
}


function handleMouseDown(e) {
    startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    draggingResizer = anchorHitTest(startX, startY);
    draggingImage = draggingResizer < 0 && hitImage(startX, startY);
}

function handleMouseUp(e) {
    draggingResizer = -1;
    draggingImage = false;
    draw(true, false);
}

function handleMouseOut(e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {

    if (draggingResizer > -1) {

        mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
        mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

        // resize the image
        switch (draggingResizer) {
            case 0:
                //top-left
                imageX = mouseX;
                imageWidth = imageRight - mouseX;
                imageY = mouseY;
                imageHeight = imageBottom - mouseY;
                break;
            case 1:
                //top-right
                imageY = mouseY;
                imageWidth = mouseX - imageX;
                imageHeight = imageBottom - mouseY;
                break;
            case 2:
                //bottom-right
                imageWidth = mouseX - imageX;
                imageHeight = mouseY - imageY;
                break;
            case 3:
                //bottom-left
                imageX = mouseX;
                imageWidth = imageRight - mouseX;
                imageHeight = mouseY - imageY;
                break;
        }

        if(imageWidth<25){imageWidth=25;}
        if(imageHeight<25){imageHeight=25;}

        // set the image right and bottom
        imageRight = imageX + imageWidth;
        imageBottom = imageY + imageHeight;

        // redraw the image with resizing anchors
        draw(true, true);

    } else if (draggingImage) {

        imageClick = false;

        mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
        mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

        // move the image by the amount of the latest drag
        var dx = mouseX - startX;
        var dy = mouseY - startY;
        imageX += dx;
        imageY += dy;
        imageRight += dx;
        imageBottom += dy;
        // reset the startXY for next time
        startX = mouseX;
        startY = mouseY;

        // redraw the image with border
        draw(false, true);

    }
}


$("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {
    handleMouseDown(e);
});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function (e) {
    handleMouseMove(e);
});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function (e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function (e) {
    handleMouseOut(e);
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overthink it. 
Edited your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mrqhpgnk/4/

1. Create an array to store old images:

   ```
   var myOldImagesArray = [];
   var atLeastOneImage = false;
   ```
2. Update in the readImage function:

   ```
   var img;

   function readImage() {
     if ( this.files && this.files[0] ) {
       var FR= new FileReader();
       FR.onload = function(e) {
         if(atLeastOneImage) {
           myOldImagesArray.push({
             image: img, X: imageX, Y: imageY, 
             width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight
           });
         }
         var img2 = new Image();
         img2.onload = function() {
           imageWidth = img2.width;
           imageHeight = img2.height;
           imageRight = imageX + imageWidth;
           imageBottom = imageY + imageHeight
           draw(true, false);
         };
         img2.src = e.target.result;
         img = img2;
         atLeastOneImage = true;
       };       
       FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
     }
   }
   ```
3. Don't forget to draw the old images while in your draw function.

   ```
   for(var i=0; i<myOldImagesArray.length; i++) {
     var oldImageDict = myOldImagesArray[i];
     var oldImage = oldImageDict.image;
     ctx.drawImage(oldImage, 0, 0, oldImage.width, oldImage.height, oldImageDict.X, oldImageDict.Y, oldImageDict.width, oldImageDict.height);
   }
   ```

I used a dictionary for the array type, since you seem to have a lot of variables pertaining to the image itself.

Also, make sure `img` is fresh. Not sure if would have worked, if had not created new variable `var img2 = new Image();` But seemed like could possibly have caused a problem, so just went ahead with my instincts there.

Comment: that solves the problem just perfect. thanks.
I actually have another problem when i try to implement that in my main project, im doing a drawing app, but either the brush works, or the images upload works.
I made this short vid if you dont minf to take a look. 

http://i.imgur.com/unfnzea.gif

Comment: damn, can only edit the comment for 5mins, but basically everytime i move/resize the image, it applies the image into the canvas, and i cant seem to solve it aswell

Comment: It's hard to say exactly what the problem is without looking at your code, but my best guess would be to: 1) Look how you are dealing with changing tools. Each tool should be independent for the most part. 2) Make it so the oldImagesArray gets updated via a button click, key return, or clicking outside the image dimensions, etc. as well as when changing tools, instead of inside the readImage() function. 3) If you aren't already, I'd also suggest to try debugging with console.log(). You can try and track the size of the oldImagesArray for example.